# java app built with gradle does not start on macOs Monterey

Tags: java, macos, gradle, macos-monterey

I'm having troubles with an application written in Java and built with gradle on Monterey.
I can build it and make a package to install it on macOS. After the installation I can see the right Icon in the Applications folder, but everytime I try to run it this dialog come out:

[image]

I think I tried everything to make it work on this OS.
On every other version of MacOS it works well.
I thought the problem could be regarding some permission, so I allowed permissions to every application like this:

[image]

but it still doesn't work.

Tried to run it via Terminal but I'm having this error:

```
The application cannot be opened for an unexpected reason, error=Error 
Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10810 "kLSUnknownErr: Unexpected internal error" 
UserInfo={_LSFunction=_LSLaunchWithRunningboard, _LSLine=2732, 
NSUnderlyingError=0x600000d3ecd0 {Error Domain=RBSRequestErrorDomain Code=5 "Launch 
failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Launch failed., 
NSUnderlyingError=0x600000d3e520 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or 
directory" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Launchd job spawn failed}}}}}
```

and I didn't find a solution for this.

I thought it could be a problem of signature of the application or something like that, but trying with these commands in a Teminal to find a solution of any type it still doesn't run.

```
codesign -v "MyApp.app"
codesign -s "MyCompany" MyApp.app
sudo xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine MyApp.app
sudo chmod -R 755 MyApp.app
sudo codesign --force --deep --sign - MyApp.app
sudo xattr -d -r com.apple.quarantine /Applications/MyApp.app
```

Nothing happened and I'm at the starting situation of not working app on Monterey.
It's not a problem of Intel or M1 chip.

What could be the solution to this problem?
I searched all internet but didn't find a solution for this.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: I can run Gradle built jar files on an M1 Mac running Montery using Zulu's build of the JDK - for me, I first run the jar, get permission denied, then upon opening Security & Privacy, a button appears to run it inside the general tab.  Though it looks like that button doesn't appear for you.